# Keep getting redirected to https when site is not

Tags: browser

I have a site that had code redirecting to https - removed code and now every browser I try still sends to https, I have cleared history, cache, cookies, ext... still redirects? same results on many machines with various browsers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out a master page in my .net had a redirect in it to force https.